# Configure S.M.A.R.T. daemon for NAS at home and suspending discs

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, monitoring, smart

I have a question about my S.M.A.R.T. daemon configuration.
I use two HDDs as RAID 1 observed with smartd. In general these are suspended, i just access them one time in two days. I've noticed the HDDs spin up every 30 minutes, because of some "checks".

- What do these checks do?
- What are offline tests for?
- What is the difference between short and long selftests?

I want to do a long test from time to time (e.g. once a month). I want to do a short test more frequently (once a week). It is useful to do an offline test daily?
Is my configuration suggestive? Do *-n suspend* suppress short and long selftests, too?

```
DEFAULT -a -o on -S on -s (O/../.././03|S/../(1|8|22)/./03|L/../15/./03) -n standby -d sat -H -m <my@email.com>
/dev/sda -M test
/dev/sdc
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Formal note: I think you ask to many questions at once. You've got no answers so far maybe because it's hard to find someone who knows all the answers while some users know one or two. The point of Super User is to have exhaustive answers, so I wouldn't bother answering if I could cover only 1/3 of your "question". I advise you to edit it and leave one actual question (or few closely connected). The others should be asked on their own with specific titles. I would split it this way: (1) checks, (2) offline tests, short/long, daily?, (3) config, (4) `-n suspend`.

Comment: Thannk you for feedback. Meanwhile I've found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for me.

1. Checks are done every 30 minutes. smartd reads the hdd and run tests if they are pending.
2. Offline tests collect data from the hdd without real "testing"
3. Short self tests check the electrical and mechanical condition of the hdd. This process might take several minutes.
4. Long self test check the whole hdd. They are usually performed in the production cycle for quality assurance. They might take some hours.
5. Furthermore there are conveyance self tests. They are performed to check the condition of the hdd after transport.
6. -n suspend suppresses the checks. The times after *-s* don't start the tests. Pending tests are performed during the next check.

My current setup suppresses repeated tasks 48 times. So after 24 hours my hdd's spin up and perform the longest pending test.

```
DEFAULT -a -o on -S on -s (S/../../6/03|L/../15/./03) -n standby,48 -d sat -m <my@email.com>
/dev/sda -M test
/dev/sdc
```